# Get relevant id for selected value in combobox in extjs

Tags: extjs, combobox

I am implemented an ExtJs combobox.

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        store : vehicleStore,
        displayField : 'vRegNum',
        valueField : 'vRegNum',
        fieldLabel : 'Vehicles',
        id : 'vehicleCombo',
        typeAhead : true,
        forceSelection : true,
        mode : 'local',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        selectOnFocus : true,
        editable : true,
        hidden : false,
        //xtype : 'combo',
        minChars : 1,
        hideLabel : true,
        style : 'marginleft:10px',
        listeners : {
            select : function() {
            }

        },
        //width : 147,
        emptyText : 'Delivery Vehicle'
        //flex : 1
    })
```

And I load this combo from postgresql database using Json.

```
var vehicleStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
fields : [ {
    id : 'vCode'
}, {
    name : 'vRegNum'
} ],
root : 'vehicles',
//autoDestroy : true,
autoLoad : true,

proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url : "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + projectName + "/"
            + "DeliveryVehicle"

}),
reader : {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'vehicles'
},
});
```

This is my DeliveryVehicle.java servlet.

```
//imports
public class DeliveryVehicle extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public DeliveryVehicle() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    ServletContext context = getServletContext();

    String dbName = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionDB");
    String connectionHost = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionHost");
    String connectionUser = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionUser");
    String connectionPassword = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionPassword");
    String port = "5433";

    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet vehicleResultSet = null;
    Connection pgConnection = null;
    //String lineString = "";

    try {
        pgConnection = ConnectionManager.getPostgresConnection(
                connectionHost, connectionUser, connectionPassword,
                dbName, port);
        //out.println(connectionHost+","+ connectionUser+","+ connectionPassword+","+ dbName);
        statement = pgConnection.createStatement();
        //out.print(pgConnection);

        String sql = "";


        sql = "select vehiclecode, registrationnumber from hoobtvehicles v WHERE v.status='1'";

        vehicleResultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        String jsonData = "{'vehicles':[";

        while (vehicleResultSet.next()) {
            jsonData += "{ 'vCode' : '";
            jsonData += vehicleResultSet.getString(1).trim();
            jsonData += "', ";
            jsonData += "'vRegNum' : '";
            jsonData += vehicleResultSet.getString(2).trim();

            if (vehicleResultSet.isLast()) {
                jsonData += "' }  ";
            } else {
                jsonData += "' } , ";
            }
        }

        jsonData += "]}";
        out.print(jsonData);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

}
```

My Json data is following.

```
{'vehicles':[{ 'vCode' : '1001', 'vRegNum' : 'XY-100-123' } , { 'vCode' : '1002', 'vRegNum' : 'GY-122-120' } , { 'vCode' : '1000000001', 'vRegNum' : 'XY-100-123' } ]}
```

My combobox is loaded fine. Now I need to get relevant vode when user select a particular vRegNum.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Try use `valueField : 'vCode'` in your combobox config. Display value will be still `vRegNum` based on `displayField` config but combo will return `vcode` as value.

Comment: I've tried it. Then the combobox always takes first vName as its' value.

Comment: If I use valueField : 'vCode' then I cannot select combobox value.it always takes the first vName as its' value. Then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( modify your code based on this snippet ) and let me know the result ( I know, I always write this sentence but I don't know what you get in your environment )

```
items: [
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'CTG ALANI',
    id: 'ctg-main',
    inputWidth: 467,
    fieldStyle: 'height: 26px',
    margin: '15 5 0 0',
    valueField: 'CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID',
    displayField: 'CTG_SECTION',
    store: ctgSection,
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoSelect: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    listeners: {
        select: function (combo) {
            ctgDescription.proxy.extraParams = {'ctgmain': combo.getValue(), 'type': 'ctg_desc'};
            ctgDescription.removeAll();
            ctgDescription.load();
        }
    }
},
```

Here is, important part `getValue()` method of the combobox. If you want only raw value of the combobox, just try `getRawValue()` method.